# javascript: how to judge a function name exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to judge if a function names exists before calling it?

Comment: tried this? `if(name_of_funcion){/*what to do then*/}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You an check `typeof` for the function, for example:

```
if(typeof this["functionName"] != "undefined") {
  alert("uh oh, doesn't exist");
}
```

If you need to check if it exists and is a function to be extra sure:

```
if(typeof this["functionName"] == "function") {
  this["functionName"](); //it exists, call it
}
```

---

Or the more relaxed version:

```
if(this["functionName"]) this["functionName"]();
```

If the name doesn't change (e.g. I misinterpreted the question) just use dot notation, like this:

```
if(this.functionName) this.functionName();
```

Or course it doesn't have to be `this`...whatever object you're checking on, use that, if it's a global function use `window`.

Comment: what if 'functionName' is not a function?

Comment: @jAndy - He's wanting a function to call that may or may not be defined... you could reverse it of course and check the `.toString()` or `typeof` for `function`, but I'd say you have bad naming overlap in those cases...often you want both, for example it may be a function or a selector, or a bool, there are several examples of this across frameworks :)

Comment: I don't know.. `this["functionName")()` would probably crash like disastrous if it's not a function object.

Comment: @jAndy - It *totally* depends on the context as to what you want here, for example your `in` check would also be the same level of type specificity here...it depends how specific you want to be, I'll update to provide the option none the less.

Answer (score 1):

depends pretty much on the scope you're in.

But in general `if( 'function_name_to_check' in this)` would return `true` if there is a property in the global or local scope which has that name.

This check must be followed by an additional check for the type:

```
if( typeof this.function_name_to_check === 'function') { }
```

to be sure that this IS a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to avoid errors, you can turn the tables:

```
try{function2call();}
catch(e){alert('function2call() doesn\'t exist');}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea in all cases, `try/catch` blocks have real performance issues, not to mention throwing an exception is *way* more expensive than the `if` checks for type.

Comment: So what do you mean why exists there a construct like try/catch, if it's bad in all cases? Try `alert('alert is a function:'+(typeof alert=='function'));` in MSIE, will this return the expected?