# Checking function exists from within jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am rolling my own jQuery form validator for a project I'm working on. I am defining the type of validation required in data-validate on the input elements.

I want to check if this validation function exists in my plugin before calling it (all within the plugin itself).

Before I have used:

```
if($.isFunction(window['functionName']))
    window['functionName']();
```

however this doesn't appear to work within my plugin:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.validateForm = function(options) {

        ...

        findInputs();

        function validateRequired(input) {

        }

        function findInputs() {

            ...

            if($(this).attr("data-validate"))
            {
                // Get list of required validation functions
                var toValidate = $(this).attr("data-validate").split(/\s+/);

                for(var i = 0; i < toValidate.length; i++) {
                    // Hardcoded function name call for testing
                    if($.isFunction(window['validateRequired']))
                        window['validateRequired']();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should work within your plugin with the hardcoded value. Are you sure the if statement is being reached?

Comment: yer I'm using if($.isFunction(window['validateRequired']))
                            console.log('yes');
                        else
                            console.log('no');

and getting 'no' outputted several times (for each input in my form ofc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to declare your functions as part of an object literal. That way, you can reference the literal within your plugin, like so:

```
(function( $ ) {
    var methods = {
        validateRequired: function(input)
        {
            // STUB
        }
    };

    $.fn.validateForm = function(options) {
        function findInputs() {

            if($.isFunction(methods['validateRequired'])) methods['validateRequired']();

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not JS expert, but try this:

```
if(typeof (someFunction) == 'function') {
// do something
}
```

EDIT

Or like this, using function name as string:

```
if(typeof this["functionName"] == "function") {
     this["functionName"](); //it exists, call it
 }
```

I found this here:

[javascript: how to judge a function name exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313462/javascript-how-to-judge-a-function-name-exists) / see Nick Craver answer.

by googling like this: "function name exists javascript"

If you are searching for something about jQuery - try to search it with javascript keyword instead of jQuery. jQuery is a framework written in javascript.

Comment: yes that would work, but I'm trying to check a function exists using a string, not the actual function itself